# Execute CURL script (Externally) from file(text) like python and e.t.c

Tags: python, curl, text-files, executable

TO execute CURL, I'm using bash.

As an example when trying to run python, you can simply just run `python aaa.py`from directory and python script will load up.

Looking for any similar way to execute curl script, like, `curl aaa.txt`, so I can just modify the actual file, and in bash just execute the same file ( which will make life a bit easier) ))

**Found the solution:**

Curl code looks like this `curl -K "aaa.txt"`

`"aaa.txt"` Should contain:

`url = "url link" -H "header"` and so on.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: @Spangen Is it should be like `curl -K "aaa.txt"` ???

Comment: Give it a go and see if it's what you need. You might need to do some research online if not